# Project order Eclipse project explorer view

Tags: java, eclipse

Is this possible in eclipse to put project in order like order by name or order which i would like to add.
I have around 30 projects in eclipse i want to see them with some order like alphabetic order. Is this possible in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define "Working Sets" (i.e a named group of projects) that can be ordered. But I think you cannot reorder the projects within those working sets (at least I've never seen such an option).

#### Edit

for information about the general usage of `workingsets` you may want to visit one of the following URLs:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#tips_workingsets

Comment: Hw to create Workingsets

Comment: Second link is dead but archive.org has a copy of it : https://web.archive.org/web/20140319234903/http://blog.manuelciosici.com/2012/04/23/what-are-eclipses-working-sets-and-why-you-should-use-them/

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these steps to rearrange your project:

```
Window-> preferences -> General -> workspace -> Build order
```

Here you can rearrange the project build order but you can not define any rule like 'All project should come in Alphabetic order'.

For more clarification visit: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-17.htm

Comment: Perfecf!, if remove check build by default order by name.